# My company has ads on SO - do they find me if I am open for job offers?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow-jobs

My company recently started to post job offers (multiple) on SO to which I am naturally a fit. HR told me they even try to get more "active" and invite people to *job breakfeasts* based on suggestions they become (not clear if SO "suggests" matching candidates or if those stem from other sources).

I am curious how

---

[image: being contacted by employers]

---

works:

- do employers get "candidate lists" based on technologies used/my interest settings?
- if I change my status, what are the chances they get *me* suggested as "candidate" to employ?

Comment: Just block the company

Comment: I believe I read somewhere that if your Developer Story shows that you are currently working at a company, this company can't see your job search status. I may have dreamed that though...

Comment: Let's hope they don't find this post as well!

Comment: @Outman: Of course, Patrick asked a purely hypothetical question here ;)

Comment: @Outman If I change my status - my employer will know the fact I did it as well as why I did so ;o) hence I am not really bothered if or if not they look on meta (which I highly doubt).

Comment: You could try checking that radio button, but a more direct approach would be to just come out and ask HR for an invite to a *job breakfeast*.  ;-)

Comment: @PatrickArtner your question is now in the "Hot Meta Posts": anyone currently _just looking_ at a regular Stack Overflow page will see the link to your question. Now, if we could just get the TweetBot and a blogger to link to your question...

Comment: @Cœur I`ll make up a blog stating "See how SO harms coders: innocent coder fired for asking at meta.SO - the dangers of SO" if anything results from it ;) - could have a better _angle_ if I was female though ... not going to go that far for my 15sec of fame

Answer (score 2):

If your employer uses Stack Overflow Talent, they will not see your profile as long as you’ve specified them as your employer in your current role.

However, there are limitations. Employee filtering works by examining the company name listed on your current role and comparing it against the companies that have access to Talent. This works in the vast majority of cases but it isn’t perfect.

- Let’s say “Elgoog” is the company you work for. All profiles that list things like “Elgoog”, “Elgoog Inc.”, or “elgoog search team” would correctly be filtered out.
- However, parent company or subsidiary names are not accounted for. So, if “Elgoog” was part of a parent company called “ABC”, profiles that list their current employer as “ABC” would not be filtered out for employers on the “Elgoog” account.

In practice, we haven’t seen this come up as an issue, since specifying something like “ABC (Elgoog)” in the previous example would be correctly filtered. However, if you’re concerned about this, please [contact our support team](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) and we’ll be happy to advise you on your specific case.

As for the job seeker status, if you set it as “Not interested in jobs”, you will not be visible to any employer on Talent. You’ll still be able to browse & apply to jobs if you choose to do so.

Setting your status to either one of the other options will result in your profile appearing in searches and automatic recommendations for suitable employers (similar to how job search and job recommendations work).